# Change viewport size of phantomJS using webdriverJS

Tags: javascript, webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver, webdriver-io

I got a problem while setting the initial window size for phantomJS using webdriverJS (https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs). What I tried was:

```
client.remote({
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: browserList[browserName] || browserList.DEV,
        size: {
            width: 1024,
            height: 768
        }
}).init();
```

However this does not seem to work as screenshots are still pretty small. Maybe I'm just missing one point in the documentation but till now I couldn't find the correct key-value-combination to get a window with the correct size.

Comment: Possilby related to this bug: https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs/issues/225

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    client
      ...
      .init()
      .windowHandleSize({width: 1024, height: 768})
```

Remove `size` from `desiredCapabilities` and add `windowHandleSize` after `init()`